# Did Cassian Andor fight on Mimban at the same time as Han Solo?

Tags: star-wars, andor

In *Andor* (S1: Ep. 4), it is revealed that Cassian Andor fought on Mimban.

Did he fight on the same side as Han Solo? Was Han one of the "50 soldiers that survived" that Andor mentions?

Comment: Han didn't survive, he deserted.

Comment: @Valorum So, you're saying that Han wasn't counted as a survivor because he was a deserter? That's interesting.

Comment: He wouldn't be counted among the survivors, since there's no good reason for the Empire to assume he survived.

Comment: @Valorum If there is an Andor: Season 2, we might see Han in a flashback on Mimban with Andor. Who knows?

Answer (score 7):

### No official confirmation, but the timeline doesn't line up

From Season 1, Episode 4: "Aldhani":

> Cassian: You don't know me. (scoffs) **I fought in Mimban when I was 16. Two years of it.** Straight out of prison, into the mud. I'm one of 50 that survived. And who did it turn out we were fighting? (scoffs) Ourselves. So, please...
>
> Luthen: **You were on the ground in Mimban for six months.** You came in as a cook. You lived because you ran. But you're right about one thing. The Empire had you fighting each other, which should make you hate them all the more, and you do.
>
> <sub>(Source: https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=1490&t=56755, emphasis added)</sub>

The 2023 reference book [*Dawn of Rebellion: The Visual Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Dawn_of_Rebellion:_The_Visual_Guide) confirms that Cassian was telling the truth about his age at the time:

> ##### MIMBAN SERVICE
>
> At age 16, Cassian serves as a cook for the ongoing Imperial campaign on Mimban, but later deserts.
>
> <sub>[*Dawn of Rebellion: The Visual Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Dawn_of_Rebellion:_The_Visual_Guide), page 63: Cassian Andor</sub>

The guide also gives Cassian's age as 27 in 5 BBY when the first season is set, putting his birth in 32 BBY. Assuming he arrived on Mimban when he was 16 and was there for up to two years, he would have been there from **16-14 BBY**.

Han was on Mimban in 10 BBY, since that's when the parts of *Solo: A Star Wars Story* set after the prologue take place. It's not clear how long he was in the flight academy before being expelled and deployed to Mimban, but there's a three-year gap between *Solo*'s prologue and the Mimban scenes, so Han was on Mimban in **13 BBY** at the absolute earliest, and definitely there by **10 BBY**, at which point he left.

It doesn't seem like there's any room for overlap—even assuming Cassian was telling the truth about being on Mimban in some capacity for two years, he'd have been gone by the time Han got there.